# Using for-in loop inside object to access its member

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

```
function Cons()
    {
        this.a = "variable a";
        this.callme = function callme()
        {
            var str = "";
                for(var x in this)
                {
                    str += this[x] + " ";
                }
            return str;
        }
    }

    var obj = new Cons();

    obj.c = "variable 2";

    var fin = obj.callme();
    document.write(fin);
```

I want to have a function inside the object so that when it is called it can return a string consisting of the values of every member. Here in this case `a` and `c`. Now what happens, everything inside the function i mean the code is printed inside the browser instead of just returning the value of `str`.

What i understood is that this["callme"] part in the for-in loop returns the whole code as its also a variable. So how to solve this problem.

I am new to javascript please help me.

Comment: What have you researched/tried so far ? I don't see any attempt of looping in the code you posted...

Comment: there is a for loop inside the callme function that creates all the problem but thats what i was trying to achieve

Comment: you can skip functions when you loop. if this is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid the function body being printed, check if the property is a function and print only its name:

```
this.callme = function callme()
    {
        var str = "";
            for(var x in this)
            {
                if ('function' === typeof this[x]) {
                    str += x + " ";
                } else {
                    str += this[x] + " ";
                }
            }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. Thanks a lot. This is what i was looking for. Can you please tell me a good guide from where can i learn more about functions and objects of javascript.

Comment: Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) is THE best place to study things about JavaScript and frontend stuff in general.

Comment: @Tibos, + for you. Here's the link [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org). As an addition - try to avoid [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) as they're no longer a **w3** branch and sometimes provide some misleading information.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solve this:

1) Remove callme from the for..in :

```
for(var x in this) {
  if (x !== 'callme') {
    str += this[x] + " ";
  }
}
```

2) Declare callme as a non-enumerable property:

```
function Cons() {
    Object.defineProperty('callme', {
      enumerable : false,
      value : function callme() {
        var str = "";
            for(var x in this)
            {
                str += this[x] + " ";
            }
        return str;
      }
    });
}
```

3) Change the toString method of callme to return nothing:

```
function Cons() {
    this.a = "variable a";
    this.callme = function callme() {
        var str = "";
            for(var x in this)
            {
                str += this[x] + " ";
            }
        return str;
    }
    this.callme.toString = function(){ return '';};
}
```

The simplest solution is the first one, but the others are too interesting to pass.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I really need to study more to understand the last two as i said i am new to js. But didn't the 1st one will only just skip the `callme` function instead of skipping all the other functions inside the object?

Comment: Yes. @matewka gave you a good answer on skipping all the functions, not just callme.